# Python JPype integration

Tags: java, python, jpype

I am using JPype The following is the code i am trying to use

```
from jpype import *

startJVM("C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll","-ea")
java.lang.System.out.println("hai")
shutdownJVM()
```

It is giving error in the execution of the println statement

```
java.lang.System.out.println("hai")
File "<stdin>", line 1
java.lang.System.out.println("hai")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can you please share a working sample of executing class' function of a jar from Python using Jpype. I was not able to find a working sample, tried a couple of with options but fail with error 'not callable'

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, are all the dependencies setup correctly? Java, Python, JPype etc?

You are trying to execute one of the first examples in the documentation.

The sample they provide in the docs are:

```
from jpype import * 
startJVM("d:/tools/j2sdk/jre/bin/client/jvm.dll", "-ea") 
java.lang.System.out.println("hello world") 
shutdownJVM()
```

One of the main differences is that you are using `\` as a path separator. As per the docs, maybe try a `/`.

Comment: Now i change my code to 
startJVM("C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_14/jre/bin/client/jvm.dll","-ea")

Still it is giving the same error

>>> java.lang.System.out.println("hello world")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    java.lang.System.out.println("hello world")
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you might just be missing a semicolon (`;`)

Comment: is it neccessary to put semicolon in python?